I am publishing a textbook. Do I need a query letter?
I am working on publishing a textbook right now that falls into Organizational Studies and Business Management. I want to publish it through a University Press if I can, like Cambridge or Oxford. I am aware that I don't need an agent for this. I was looking at Oxford's process, and they weren't specific on whether or not I would first send a query letter and then a book proposal or if a query letter isn't needed... I'm assuming there is a norm for academic publishing that I am not aware of. So my questions are:

with academic nonfiction publishing, do I generally need to send a query letter, or just my book proposal?
Is it common courtesy to put that in the body of the email or in an attached document if there is no specification?
if no query letter is needed, and usually it's common to just attach a document, what would I put in the body of the email?
Are query letters generally for literary agents and not publishers?

Still trying to wrap my head around the purpose of the query letter vs book proposal and the culture around that.

You are not publishing it; you are writing it and you are looking for a publisher. It's important to get this right. :)

Query letters are for both agents and publishers.
Generally you still send a query letter, one page, so the publisher (or agent) can decide if they are interested in your book.
You should have a book proposal ready if they are interested, they will ask for that. The book proposal is up to 50 pages, includes one or more sample chapters, an overview, the target audience, your credentials for writing it, competitive titles, etc.
And there are agents for non-fiction work, and they can help you.
The contents of the query letter or book proposal are not straightforward, but there are many online sites giving guidelines and advice. There are also former literary agents that will review your query letter, for a few hundred $$. In general they are worth it, if the fee is fixed and what you get is well described, like a written line by line critique of your query letter and advice.
Beware of anybody promising you unrealistic service; "getting you published!" is an area filled with frauds. Beware of anybody promising to represent you if you pay their fee; all true agents work strictly on commission, if they ask for a fee, they are a fraud. Period.
Same thing with agents, if they charge any sort of fee to read, either your query letter or the sample chapters or your book, don't bother. Agents make their money by commission on sold books, and nothing else.
The "culture" is that agents (or publishers that take queries directly) reject about 95% to 99% of the stuff people submit without request.
Seriously, the rejection rate is very high. Many people think they can write, that writing is easy, and writing is easy money. Nearly all of them are wrong.
Agents and Publishers (or publisher readers) can judge writing fast. I've heard an agent say all they have to see is somebody write "I have written a fiction novel" and in the reject pile it goes.
The query letter is the first indication, to an agent/reader, if you know how to write and how to deliver what they expect. If it has typos, if the grammar is off, if it sounds like braggadocio, or begging, or is trying to bribe them ("I'll split the profits with you!") into representing you, in the reject pile it goes.
Agents know publishers, and meet with publishers frequently, and they know what publishers are looking for.
If at any point the publisher doesn't trust the agent to be on their side, and bring them quality writing that is publishable, they stop seeing that agent.
The agent knows multiple publishers, and acts as their quality filter; the agent will not bring them crap.
Many publishers rely exclusively on agents for this reason, they don't want to pay readers to sort through 99% crap to get to the good stuff. The publishers accept the higher prices they have to pay for books (because the agent is an expert negotiator) to simplify their life -- They are going to read a decent book vetted by the agent, that is in their current area of interest to publish.
The agent, on the other hand, gets their paycheck entirely from commission on sales; so they are going to negotiate the highest price they can for their authors. And they have the expertise to do that. You probably do not, and a publisher might reject you just because you don't know the business and what things are worth.
Using an agent is not the difference between getting 100% and getting 85%, it is usually the difference between getting 85% and getting 0%, for an unsold manuscript.
The purpose of the query letter is to prove to a reader/agent that you know how to write and you know how to provide what is expected, and you know how to generate and hold interest. That is just as important for a non-fiction book as it is for a fiction book; both must be entertaining, or they won't sell.


You always send a query letter.
The query letter is your email, if you query by email.
For fiction, you usually submit (part of) your manuscript with your query letter; for non-fiction, both popular and academic, you usually submit a book proposal* with your query letter.
Manuscript or book proposals are attached to the email, if you query by email.
Agents and publishers can have their own guidelines. Look on their website.


* Commonly publishers of non-fiction want to have a say in the focus, structure, and presentation of the text.
